# How to query first and last objects from an array in MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb

So, I have an array of objects like this one:

```
"coordinates":[
   {
      "action":"charge",
      "position":{
         "city":"City A"
      }
   },
   {
      "action":"charge",
      "position":{
         "city":"City B"
      }
   },
   {
      "action":"discharge",
      "position":{
         "city":"City C"
      }
   },
   {
      "action":"discharge",
      "position":{
         "city":"City D"
      }
   },
   (...)
]
```

This array has a number N of objects, so I don't know the total of objects inside the array.

My question is: How do I query the first and last city from the object position of the coordinates array? I was doing something like this:

```
db.find({
        'coordinates.0.position.city': city_first_name, 
        'coordinates.position': {'$elemMatch': {'city': city_last_name}
    }, 
    {
        'coordinates.$.position': {'$slice': -1}})
    })
```

But that didn't work really well. It gets the first position, but will get any element that is in any part of any object. Should I use aggregation or there is another way using find?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: It's better to get whole list of coordinates from mongo by simple find and do python list operations to get first and last items. Eg list[0]["position"]["city"] and list[-1]["position"]["city"]

Answer (score 0):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "f": {
        "$slice": [//Firsgt
          "$a",
          1
        ]
      },
      "l": {
        "$slice": [//Last
          "$a",
          -1
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

You could achieve using `$slice` with `$project`

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/YH0vV3WxWVS)